# Execute independent greps in a single shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I have several grep filters that I usually use to parse specific information.

1st grep: `grep "pattern1\|pattern2\|pattern3\|" file.txt`

2nd grep: `grep "patternA\|patternB\|patternC\|" file.txt`

etc.

I apply each grep usually to the same `file.txt`
to get an independent output.

I would like to know how I can group this bunch of greps into a single bash script in order to get independent outputs based on each type of grep.

For example: input `file.txt` looks as follows:

```
This line1 is the first line in here1
This line2 is the second line in here2
This line3 is the third line in here3
This line4 is the fourth line in here4
```

I usually apply separate greps here to get specific patterns.

```
grep -h -r --color=always "line1\|here1" file.txt >>pattern1.txt
```

or

```
grep -h -r --color=always "line2\|here2" file.txt >>pattern2.txt
```

This will highlight only the information required and will give me separate `pattern*.txt` files to work on. The objective here is to run all these greps in a single time to evaluate the same file and print in shell as follows:

- `Pattern1`
- `Pattern2`
- `Pattern3`

etc.

Each grep should evaluate the complete file independently.

Comment: This question would benefit a lot from you [editting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/356158/edit) it to include sample input and desired output.  Also, check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Yes, please [edit]  and clarify. Give us a sample input and the specific grep commands you would run and show us the output you want to see. I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking right now.

Comment: I have input  a sample, hope now is more clear.

Comment: How are you getting from your `grep` criteria to the name "Pattern1" as the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly,
it’s about how to do the same command (`grep`),
with the same options and the same input,
but multiple times,
with different regex arguments and different outputs. 
And I guess you want to avoid unnecessary repetition/duplication.

It seems like you want an array of regular expressions (search strings):

```
declare -A regex
regex[1]="line1\|here1"
regex[2]="line2\|here2"
regex[3]="line3\|here3"
regex[4]="line4\|here4"

for i in "${!regex[@]}"
do
        grep -h -r --color=always "${regex["$i"]}" file.txt >> "pattern$i.txt"
done
```

The first line (`declare -A regex`) declares an associative array
called `regex`; that means it creates the array as a placeholder,
but doesn't enter any information (elements) into it. 
The next four lines populate the array with four elements,
which are the regular expressions,
indexed by the numbers `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. 
(I’m using those indices because that’s what you seem to want,
but you can use any distinct strings as indices:
for example, `uno`, `dos`, `tres` and `cuatro`,
or `ant`, `bat`, `cat` and `dog`.<sup>†</sup>) 
The `for` statement, `for i in "${!regex[@]}"`,
causes the variable `i` to iterate through
the index values `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. 
(If I had left out the `!` and said `for i in "${regex[@]}"`,
it would have iterated through the element values,
`line1\|here1`, `line2\|here2`, `line3\|here3` and `line4\|here4`.) 
When `$i` is `1`, `${regex["$i"]}` reduces to `${regex[1]}`,
which expands to `line1\|here1`. 
So, the loop iterates (executes) four times,
executing the four `grep` commands that you want.

If you want to run the `grep` processes in parallel, just do:

```
for i in "${!regex[@]}"
do
        grep -h -r --color=always "${regex["$i"]}" file.txt >> "pattern$i.txt" &
done
wait
```

______________
<sup>†</sup> If the indices
are numerically distinct non-negative integers,
you can leave out the `declare` statement.

Comment: Thanks!, it is working as expected, however, if I use strings as indices for the `regex`, it doesn't work, for example: `regex[test_one]="line1\|here1"`, is there something I'm missing here?. When using strings the for loop exits after evaluating the first grep.

Comment: Sorry; it's my fault — I left out a line. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks G-man, I  believe it should work but doing some research, `declare -A` is available from bash v4.0, unfortunately I'm a mac OS X user and bash is available up to v3.2.57, I'm thinking to use python instead to use dictionaries as associative arrays, currently this is what I get as an output: `declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]`

Comment: Well, as I said, if you use numbers as indices, you don’t need to `declare` the array at all.